# Akka cluster: why don't I receive a UnreachableMember event when a member is marked unreachable?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-cluster

I would like to change the behaviour of a cluster node when an other node is unreachable. That's why I want to bet informed when an other member is unreachable.

When a member is unreachable, I can see it in the logs:

```
[warn] a.c.ClusterCoreDaemon - Cluster Node [akka.tcp://application@127.0.0.1:2554] - Marking node(s) as UNREACHABLE [Member(address = akka.tcp://application@127.0.0.1:40550, status = Up)].
```

But in the actor monitoring the cluster events (working since I can see when a member joins or is up), I don't receive this event by doing:

```
case UnreachableMember(member) =>
  log.info("Member unreachable: {}", member.address)
```

Am I doing something wrong or do I have to add something in the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't receive this event because I didn't subscribe well to cluster events.

I did this:

```
cluster.subscribe(
  self,
  InitialStateAsEvents,
  classOf[MemberEvent])
```

instead of this:

```
cluster.subscribe(
  self,
  InitialStateAsEvents,
  classOf[MemberEvent],
  classOf[UnreachableMember])
```

So I had to add classOf[UnreachableMember] and now I receive the Unreachable cluster events.